How does one prove this inclusion of a set?
I've recently come across the Cauchy's original proof for arithmetic-geometric inequality. In it, he does a proof by induction over a set $A$. Firstly he proves that $P_n\implies P_{2n}$ and then that $P_{n+1}\implies P_{n}$. Here for all $n \in A$. So this obviously necessitates that $A=\mathbb{N^*}$. I have tried to formulate a proof for this, but I cannot convince myself that I am correct, can somebody guide me or tell me if I am wrong?
Proof:
Consider $A\subset \mathbb{N^*}\wedge 1\in A$ such that:
i) if $n\in A$, $2n\in A$
ii) $n+1\in A \implies n\in A$
Firstly, let's prove by induction that if $n$ is a power of two, then it is in $A$:
Proceed by induction for $m$ over $\mathbb{N}$ and let $P_m: 2^m\in A$
$P_0 = 2^0 = 1\in A$ by definition of A
consider $P_m$ true:
Because $2^m\in A$, by i) $2^{m+1}\in A$
Now we prove that for some $k \in \mathbb{N^*}$,  $n+k \in A \implies n\in A$
By induction, let $P_k: n+k \in A \implies n\in A$ for $k \ge 1$
$P_1$ is true since by ii) $n+1\in A \implies n\in A$
Consider $P_k$ true:
$n+k\in \mathbb{N^*}$ thus by ii), $n+k+1\in A \implies n+k\in A \implies n\in A$
Now here comes the part I'm not too sure of:
If $n$ is a power of 2 then $n\in A$
If not, since $n+k\in \mathbb{N^*}$, we can take $k=2^m-n$ so $n+k= 2^m\in A$
Thus $\forall n\in \mathbb{N^*}, n\in A$ so $\mathbb{N^*}\subset A$ but by A's definition, $A \subset \mathbb{N^*}$, so $\mathbb{N^*} = A$
Is this proof correct?

Your proof is correct but the following variant is simpler. Let $P_k: n+k \in A \implies n\in A$ for $k \ge0$.
$P_0$ is obvious, and by ii), $P_k\implies P_{k+1}$. Now, every $n\in\Bbb N$ is $\le 2^m$ for some $m$, which by the first induction belongs to $A$, so by the second induction applied to $k:=2^m-n$, $n\in A$.

Thank you very much!
